# Bootstrap : navigation toggle button issue in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

i have coded website  using bootstrap 3.0 . it looks good for mobile and deskstop but  when i  view it in  mobile then   its menu does not work properly .  it goes responsive but when i click on it to expand or collapse it  remains expanded ,

This is my  navbar code . Whats wrong with it some  one please help me with it ,

```
   <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"> 
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
    <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="about-us.php" class="dropdown-toggle"  role="button" 
    arial-expanded="false">About us</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="chairman-message.php">Chairman's Message  </a></li>
  <li><a href="work.php">Work </a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Board</a></li>
</ul>
<li><a href="intro.php">Indtroduction </a></li>
<li><a href="intro.php">Indtroduction </a></li></ul>
```

Comment: Did you add jQuery and Bootstrap's JavaScript library?

Comment: yes i did  i am using smartmenu  that i added in it